# JTS Topology Suite 1.15.0 on build.gradle

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, build.gradle, jts

I want to use JTS Topology Suite 1.15.0 in my Android Studio project. I used 1.13 before from vividsolutions. Now i can't find a build.gradle code for 1.15.0. Maven code for it is like [this](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/USING.md).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jts.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So in my gradle i wrote

```
compile group: 'org.locationtech.jts', name: 'jts-core', version: '1.15'
```

But it failed to resolve the package. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `version: '1.15.0'`. The actual download location is `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/locationtech/jts/jts-core/1.15.0/` so you are required to add the .0 to the version number.

In Gradle 3 it's: `implementation 'org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.15.0'`